# Unable to play local mp3 file stored in documents directory using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudioplayer

I have an mp3 audio file generated on an Samsung android device. I download this same file from a server and store in documents directory. Now I use the code below to play this audio file. iAudioFileURL is a property that I use externally to set the audio file url. When the url is set I set up the AVAudioPlayer for that url using the code below

```
var iAudioFileURL : URL?{
    didSet{
        if let audioFileURL = iAudioFileURL {
            if audioFileURL.isFileURL {
                if let previousURL = iAVAudioPlayer?.url {
                    if previousURL.path == audioFileURL.path {
                        return
                    }
                }

                self.stopPlayer()
                self.iToolBar.items?[0] = iPlayButton

                do {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers])
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    try iAVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL)
                } catch  let error as NSError {
                    iError = error
                    return
                }
                iError = nil
                iAVAudioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                self.iProgressSlider.minimumValue = 0
                if let duration = self.iAVAudioPlayer?.duration {
                    let durationNumber = NSNumber(floatLiteral: duration)
                    self.iProgressSlider.maximumValue = durationNumber.floatValue
                }
            } else {
                print("Path:\(iAudioFileURL?.path) is not a file url")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine for other files, but for all mp3 files generated from that device fail to play. 
I have a button which triggers the play method of **AVAudioPlayer** instance.
I have referred most of the questions and answers from stackoverflow. They dont provide me a solution for my case. Even the methods dont throw errors. Please help me out.You can find the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B857HaBQcvOtckMzYWljM3JHNkk)

Comment: how are you generating mp3 file?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I am recording the file

Comment: How to save the file in mp3 format? may be it's not saved in mp3 format

Comment: @SaurabhJain when its recorded its mp3 already. Then its uploaded to server where its not converted to any other format as I have confirmed. Then I download it using URLSession task. Then I try playing it.

Comment: try to check it's not recorded in mp3 format, I am sure.

Comment: @SaurabhJain the mimetype of the file is audio/x-hx-aac-adts. Is this mimtyoe supported on iOS?. I couldn't find a credible source confirming it.

Comment: @SaurabhJain thanks I found a credible source https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2365009?tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was even if the extension was mp3 the mimetype of the file was audio/x-hx-aac-adts. In this thread [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2365009?tstart=0][1] varjak paw replies

> iTunes, to the best of my knowledge, does not support AAC in ADTS
>   (Audio Data Transport Stream), only AAC in MPEG-4. You'll need to find
>   a converter to get these files into MPEG-4 before iTunes will be able
>   to read them. Sorry, I can't offer any suggestions as to a converter
>   to try.
>
> Regards.

So this makes it clear that files with mimetype audio/x-hx-aac-adts are not supported.
You can open terminal on mac and use the command below to get mimetypes of files

> file --mime-type -b myfile.extension